# CSS attribute to backbone el view

Tags: javascript, html, css, backbone.js

Is it possible in backbone to add an empty attribute such as data-equalizer:

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
```

My backbone view looks like this:

```
MyApp.Views.UserPanelInnerContainerView = Support.CompositeView.extend({

className: "row",
initialize: function(){
},
render: function(){
}
});
```

I can add class of row using className, but how do i add data-equalizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
className: "userPanelInnerContainerView",
attributes: {
    "data-equalizer": ""
},
```

Reference:
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes